# webpack css loader doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, webpack-style-loader

Hello I'm trying to load bootstrap css through webpack style-loader in my vue2js SPA.

I installed style loader with `npm install --save-dev css-loader` and I've got it in `devDependiecies` of `package.json`. I also added following to my [webpack.conf.js](https://gist.github.com/6b7e4da3478bb15d7465e3dc5152dfd2):

```
  {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
  }
```

Then I installed bootstrap css throught

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.3
```

And last thing I did is import bootstrap css in main.js

```
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import '../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
```

I also tried like this:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
```

and like this:

```
import './../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import './../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
```

This doesn't work giving me this error in command line(AFTER SERVER START):

> ERROR in ./src/main.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css' in 'C:\Users\Adm\Documents\TheStockerTrader\src'
>    @ ./src/main.js 7:0-62
>    @ multi main
>
> ERROR in ./src/main.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in 'C:\Users\Adm\Documents\TheStockerTrader'
>    @ ./src/main.js 6:0-58
>    @ multi main

And this errors in chrome console:

> resolve 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css' in 'C:\Users\Adm\Documents\TheStockerTrader\src'
>     Parsed request is a module
>     using description file: C:\Users\Adm\Documents\TheStockerTrader\package.json (relative path: ./src)
>       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css' in 'C:\Users\Adm\Documents\TheStockerTrader\src'

What I'm doing wrong, why my css-loader doesn't work? It says that it can't find bs module but I'm sure I installed it, I also checked if it is present in my node_modules folder and it is:

[image: files structure]

Comment: Can you share your web pack.config.js file?

Comment: Just click link above in question.

Comment: tell me your `webpack` version?

Comment: it's in package.json `"webpack": "2.1.0-beta.25",` I also edit second error and copied more of its.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you install style loader as well:

```
npm install style-loader --save-dev
```

Then set as a loader:

```
{
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I am facing a similar error. Inspite of installing css-loader and style-loader I get the error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70075787/config-error-in-stylesheets-of-application-with-npm-run-dev

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
module : {
    rules : [
...
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
          loader: 'raw-loader'
        },
        // // css global which not include in components
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          exclude: path.join(__dirname, '/src/app'),
          use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            use: 'raw-loader'
          })
        },
    ]...
}
plugin : [
    ...
    new ExtractTextPlugin(
        '[name].css'
    ),
]
```

Comment: thanks for your time but answer above was actually correct and i didn't even try your code.